# Is there a way to completely ignore dynamic requires in webpack?

Tags: webpack

I'm working on an [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) app that uses dynamic requires to load in extensions (node modules) during run-time. The app currently gets an array of installed extensions loops through them, require's them and save's references to them:

```
getInstalledExtensions()
  .then(extensions => {
    extensions.map(extension => require(extension.path))
  })
  .then(saveExtensions)
```

I'm having trouble getting webpack to **completely ignore** the require statement on the third line: `require(extension.path)`.

The list of installed extensions is not known at build time. When a user first installs the app the array is empty, it grows/shrinks as the user installs/uninstalls extensions.

I've tried:

```
module: {
    exprContextRegExp: /$^/,
    exprContextCritical: false,
}
```

but it just replaces `require(extension.path)` with

```
!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \".\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }())
```

**Why do I want to use webpack in an electron app?**

`require` is expensive and it affects my app's startup time considerably. As an example, `require('request')` takes about 800ms which is ridiculous. I'd like to bundle as many modules as I can to reduce my app's startup time.

I'd also like to have the possibility of using CSS loaders. I'm currently using a mix of global classes and inline styles, which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with making an yeoman package for atom. My solution is folowing:

1. Create in output folder "originalRequire.js" file with only one line: module.exports = require.
2. In webpack config mention "./originalRequire" in externals section (so it will not process and include originalRequire into build).
3. Use string-replace-loader for replace require with require("./originalRequire"). In your example it will be require("./originalRequire")(extension.path).

Comment: This solution worked well for me. Thanks!

Edit: I didn't use the string-replace-loader - just sticking originalrequire.js in the externals was all I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.require()` instead of `require()` in electron.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack does not support fully dynamic expressions in import and require. There is hacky solution provided by the webpack in such situation which I think is very ugly. You can use the magic comment provided by webpack. For this, you include a comment **webpackIgnore: true**  inside your import/require method.

```
require(/* webpackIgnore: true */ 'ignored-module')

getInstalledExtensions()
  .then(extensions => {
    extensions.map(extension => require(/* webpackIgnore:true */ extension.path))
  })
  .then(saveExtensions)
```

There is another option you can try. Check the webpack plugin [webpack-ignore-dynamic-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-ignore-dynamic-require).The plugin simply ignores require() if it has non string expression which in **your** case is require(extension.path).

Comment: ravi, please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.